# The App seems no need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission when I ask it to store file in data/data/com.myapp (getApplicationInfo().dataDir) root

Tags: android

This confuses me a lot when I test my app on android 6.0+ devices.Since in android 6.0+,we should ask the user to accept some dangerous permissions.I pressed refuse button when it ask me for

> WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

permission and then,if my file cache path was `data/data/com.myapp(getApplicationInfo().dataDir)`,it can still be cached. And for any other path e.g. 
`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`,it won't be cached.

So why does this happen?

Comment: Is it because that getApplicationInfo().dataDir is not ExternalStorage?